# Issues about mixing usage of HTML5 History API, css selectors and the jQuery's smooth-scrolling plugin

Tags: html, css-selectors, url-routing, single-page-application, pushstate

In my SPA webpage I used the [juizy-slideshow](http://www.creativejuiz.fr/trytotry/juizy-slideshow-full-css3-html5/) which makes an abusive use of the css :target pseudo-class for its play/pause/next/prev/dots commands.. and myself I used more :targets in the webpage for scrolling up and down between its several sections and for this effect, I also used the [jquery's smooth-scrolling plugin](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) taking control of each :target's scrolling to smooth it and I had to make exceptions on it not to consider the juizy-slideshow's :targets and till here everything worked fine.

This is the slider code html part:

```
  <div id="Accueil">
   <div id="s_w_wrap">
      <div id="sliderwrap">
         <div id="slider"  style="position:absolute;right:-15px;top:20px;width:60%;">
            <span id="Pause_defiler_accueil" class="sl_command">&nbsp;</span>
            <span id="Nos_services" class="sl_command sl_i">&nbsp;</span>
            <span id="Nos_references" class="sl_command sl_i">&nbsp;</span>
            <span id="Contactez_nous" class="sl_command sl_i">&nbsp;</span>                                 
            <section id="slideshow">                    
               <a class="commands prev commands1 cmdlink" href="#Contactez_nous" title="Contact">&lt;</a>
               <a class="commands next commands1 cmdlink" href="#Nos_references" title="Nos Réfs">&gt;</a>
               <a class="commands prev commands2 cmdlink" href="#Nos_services" title="Nos Services">&lt;</a>
               <a class="commands next commands2 cmdlink" href="#Contactez_nous" title="Contact">&gt;</a>
               <a class="commands prev commands3 cmdlink" href="#Nos_references" title="Nos Réfs">&lt;</a>
               <a class="commands next commands3 cmdlink" href="#Nos_services" title="Nos Services">&gt;</a>                        
               <a id="cmdpause" class="play_commands pause cmdlink" href="#Pause_defiler_accueil" title="Stopper l'animation">Pause</a>
               <a id="cmdplay" class="play_commands play cmdlink" href="#Defiler_accueil" title="Lancer l'animation">Play</a>                           
            </section>
            <div class="container">
               <div class="c_slider"></div>
               <div class="slider">
                  <figure id="servsfig">
                     <img src="images/sliderimgs/prods.jpg" alt="" width="440" height="310" />
                     <figcaption>~~ Nos services ~~</figcaption>
                  </figure>
                  <!--
                     -->
                  <figure id="refsfig">
                     <img src="images/sliderimgs/nos_references.jpg" alt="" width="440" height="310" />
                     <figcaption>~~ Nos références ~~</figcaption>
                  </figure>
                  <!--
                     -->
                  <figure id="contfig">
                     <img src="images/sliderimgs/phoneus.png" alt="" width="440" height="310" />
                     <figcaption>~~ Contactez-nous! ~~</figcaption>
                  </figure>
               </div>
            </div>
            <span id="timeline"></span>                     
            <ul class="dots_commands">
               <!--
                  -->
               <li><a class="cmdlink" title="Nos services" href="#Nos_services">Nos services</a></li>
               <!--
                  -->
               <li><a class="cmdlink" title="Nos références" href="#Nos_references">Nos références</a></li>
               <!--
                  -->
               <li><a class="cmdlink" title="Contactez-nous!" href="#Contactez_nous">Contactez-nous!</a></li>
            </ul>
            </section>  
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and this is a part of its CSS part :

```
.sl_i:target ~ #slideshow .slider                               { visibility: hidden }
.sl_i:target ~ #slideshow .txtslider                                { visibility: hidden }
.sl_i:target ~ #slideshow .txtslider2                           { display: block } 


.sl_i:target ~ #slideshow .slider figcaption                        { visibility: hidden }
.sl_i:target ~ #slideshow .dots_commands li:first-child a:after     { display:none; }
.sl_i:target ~ #slideshow .dots_commands li:first-child a:before    { display:block; }}

#Nos_services:target ~ #slideshow .commands                             { display: none; }
#Nos_services:target ~ #slideshow .commands1                                { display: block; }
#Nos_services:target ~ #slideshow .c_slider                             { background-position: 0 0, 440px 0, 880px 0, 1320px 0; }
#Nos_services:target ~ #slideshow .txtslider2                           { left: 0}
#Nos_services:target ~ #slideshow .txtslider                            { left: 0}

#Nos_services:target ~ #slideshow .dots_commands li:first-child a:before    { left:0; }

#Nos_references:target ~ #slideshow .commands                               { display: none; }
#Nos_references:target ~ #slideshow .commands2                          { display: block; }
#Nos_references:target ~ #slideshow .c_slider                               { background-position: -440px 0, 0 0, 440px 0, 880px 0; }
#Nos_references:target ~ #slideshow .txtslider2                         { left: -100%}
#Nos_services:target ~ #slideshow .txtslider                            { left: -100%}

#Nos_references:target ~ #slideshow .dots_commands li:first-child a:before  { left:18px; }

#Contactez_nous:target ~ #slideshow .commands                               { display: none; }
#Contactez_nous:target ~ #slideshow .commands3                          { display: block; }
#Contactez_nous:target ~ #slideshow .c_slider                               { background-position: -880px 0, -440px 0, 0 0, 440px 0; }
#Contactez_nous:target ~ #slideshow .txtslider2                         { left: -200%}
#Nos_services:target ~ #slideshow .txtslider                            { left: -200%}
#Contactez_nous:target ~ #slideshow .dots_commands li:first-child a:before  { left:36px; }
```

And this is the jquery's smooth-scrolling code:

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#], [href=#Defiler_accueil], [href=#Pause_defiler_accueil], [href=#Defiler_services], [href=#Pause_defiler_services], [href=#Defiler_references], [href=#Pause_defiler_references], [href^=#sl_i], [href=#Nos_services], [href=#Nos_references], [href=#Contactez_nous], [href=#Parquet_stratifie], [href=#Rideaux_lamelles], [href=#Moquette], [href=#Plancher_technique], [href=#Cloison_en_plaque_de_platre], [href=#Plafond_demontable], [href=#Usine_menuiserie_aluminium], [href=#Pharmacie_Ben_Youssef], [href=#PIZZA_HUT_Tunis_Mal_Lac], [href=#Tunis_Mall_Lac])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

        var target = $(this.hash);
        history.pushState('', '', '/' + this.hash.slice(1));
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Now i get aqcuinted with the html5 pushstate(HTML5 History API) and i liked that it will make my page's links having a REST style instead of the ugly #s and then problems started :

1) [say if correct] For the scrollings targets when using the pushstate, it wasn't problem at all as they refer all of them to a first level paths (e.g http://localhost/my-app-foldername-in-www/home/) but the pushstate removes the app domain name (my-app-foldername-in-www) and i got urls like : localhost/home , localhost/Products. I suppose here that later when the app will be hosted in a server then "localhost" will be replaced by my-app-foldername-in-www which will become the domain name itself and urls will be "my-app-foldername-in-www/products" so it won't be problem anymore.

2) In almost every section (/home, /Products..) i used a juizy-slideshow so here i wanted urls with 2-level path (e.g /Products/stuff (second levels correspond to the slides indeed which are controlled by css selectors to trigger sliding transitions like : `#stuff:target ~ #slideshow .c_slider{ background-position: -440px 0, 0 0, 440px 0, 880px 0; }`. First i simply replaced classes names and identifiers (used initially as hrefs for the :targets) by their absolute paths like `#Products/stuff:target ~ #slideshow .c_slider{ background-position: -440px 0, 0 0, 440px 0, 880px 0; }` but this won't be accepted by CSS(nor when adding them to the smooth scroll plugin exceptions) and transitions stopped working. So i decided to keep these classes and ids names for the CSS and just use the absolute paths in the urls when using the pushstate :

```
                $(".cmdlink").on("click", function(event){
                    //event.preventDefault();

                    var accu_arr = ["stuff1", "stuff2", "stuff3"];
                    var newurl = this.hash.slice(1);

                    if($.inArray( newurl, accu_arr) != '-1')
                        newurl = "Products/"+newurl;

                    console.log('cmdlink : newurl 1: '+newurl);
                    history.pushState('', '', newurl+'/');  
                });
```

but it still doesn't make css transitions work as if CSS selectors depend on urls too. What can i do for this?

3) I also faced another problem when clicking more then one of these several double-level path commands which is that every time it makes accumulate paths pushed by the pushstate and i got urls like http://localhost/Products/stuff1/Products/stuff2/Products/stuff3/Products/stuff1. One-level paths don't make such as problem and update the whole url instead : so passing from localhost/Products to localhost/otherSection work fine. How to manage this?

Answer (score 0):

window.hashchange solved my problem :

```
        $(window).on("hashchange", function() {
                var hash = location.hash;
                //covert hash to /hash and make a newurl here..                     
                history.pushState('', '', newurl);               

        });
```